# On a default Linode instance, can I check email remotely?

Tags: ubuntu, email, email-server, vps, linode

Please allow me to ask a stupid question but I have a Linode instance that I use for web hosting.  I use Google apps for email so I didn't install anything other than what came with my Ubuntu install there.  Since my site has some cron jobs running, if one fails (which happens from time to time), I get a message when I ssh in that says I have new mail.  I installed Mutt and check it that way but for convenience sake, I'd LOVE to just use Apple Mail locally.  The reason I think my question is stupid is because I didn't install a mail server yet I still feel there has to be one if I'm getting local mail, right?  It seems like I should have an email address like username@12.34.56.78 or whatever the IP is.

Basically, I don't want to SSH in every time I want to check my email.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide!

Comment: Why don't you just have the server deliver mail to your Gmail account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The reason I think my question is stupid is because I didn't install a
>   mail server yet I still feel there has to be one if I'm getting local
>   mail, right?

Right. It's Ubuntu, therefore the MTA is [Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix).

> Basically, I don't want to SSH in every time I want to check my email.

As the inimitable Michael Hampton said in the comment on your question, just have Postfix forward your mail to gmail. And before you ask "How do I do that?" there are two things to note:

1. Your question is probably answered over at [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) wonderful Postfix documentation. At ServerFault we encourage people to read as much official documentation, and get their hands as dirty as they possibly can before asking a question about a topic that's blocking progress.
2. Ask a new question, not an additional one in this Question. At ServerFault we encourage people to ask discrete questions, not edit original Questions and expand the scope.

Hugs.

Comment: Much appreciated to both of you!  I think I needed just this push in the right direction so I knew what to Google.  I actually did Google this but it's hard to find something when you don't know what you're looking for but you have helped me out!  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisFarrugia All good in the 'hood. Enjoy your descent into Postfix. Good luck with the resulting alcoholism. -_-